# How do we compare points in 2-dimensional and 3-dimensional Euclidean space?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider the following example:

Let there be point $p_1$ and $p_2$ in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^1$, its dimension named $x$. Suppose $p_1$ has a $x$ value of 5 and $p_2$ has a $x$ value of 10.

In this world, we can conclude that the inequality $p_1<p_2$ is true because $5<10$.

My questions:

1. If we have the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^2$, how are the points compared?
2. If we have the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$, how are the points compared?
3. If it is not clear from the answers to questions (1) and (2), is there a pattern that can help me identify how the points are compared in higher-dimensional Euclidean spaces ($\mathbb{R}^4,\mathbb{R}^5,\mathbb{R}^6,...\mathbb{R}^n$)?

Regarding question (1), by visualizing two points on an $xy$ plane like we did in high school geometry, the *lower* point is the one closest to the origin, correct? If that is the case, then we would run into a problem when, say both points have the same $x$ or $y$ coordinate. And technically there is no order to the dimensions ($x$ is not necessarily before $y$, or vice-versa), so how can we compare the points in this case?

Comment: The lexicographic order ? However, generally speaking, one does not compare points in higher dimensions !

Comment: Yes, the lexicographic order, thank you; it was at the tip of my tongue! As I was saying, we usually write, e.g., $x,y,z$, but these dimensions do not *exist* in any particular order. So, you said that we do not compare points in higher dimensions. Would this be because of the previously stated? On the flip-side, if one were to define the *order* of dimensions in a particular space, we could.